# mysql tables identifying as Antelope rather than Barracuda

Tags: mysql

I have my innodb_file_format setting set to Barracuda, however when I create new tables without specifying the row_format, they appear as Antelope.

Why is this and is there a way to change this behavior? Do I HAVE to specify the row_format with all tables I create if I want them to use Barracuda?

Comment: Does the variable `innodb_file_per_table` enabled?. See [innodb_file_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format).

Comment: Yes, it's enabled.

Comment: What version of MySQL Server are you using?. `In MySQL 5.7.8 and earlier, rows are stored in COMPACT format by default.`. See [15.9.2 Specifying the Row Format for a Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format-specification.html).